# OrchardCMS layout of admin pages

Tags: layout, admin, orchardcms

I'm trying to change the layout of the admin page for a type and I'm struggling. The client is very specific on the order of the fields and I'm not sure how to do it.

I've created an admin theme and changed the placement.info, but it doesn't seem to work. Are there any hooks I could use to accomplish this?

Any help much appreciated.

My placement.info in the admin theme.

```
  <Match ContentType="Course">
    <Place Parts_Routable_Edit="Content:1" />
    <Place Fields_Contrib_TaxonomyField_Edit="Content:2" />
    <Place Parts_Taxonomies_Term_Fields="Content:2.5" />
    <Place Parts_MediaPickerField_Edit="Content:3" />
    <Place Parts_Course_Edit="Content:4" />
    <Place Parts_Tags_Edit="Content:5" />
  </Match>
```

There's also another problem. I would like 3 taxonomies, and have them placed in different areas of the admin screen. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 1.5, you can change the order of parts and fields in the editor, from the admin dashboard. Go to Content Types, select the type, then click on "Manage Placement". You can then drag and drop parts and fields around.

Answer (score 1):

Note that admin themes need to contain a IThemeSelector implementation that gives it a priority of more than 100, which is the priority of the default admin theme.

Comment: Hi - the admin theme is definitely getting used, as it's used for something else that is showing up.

Comment: Carl, did you ever come up with a solution for this? I'm in the exact same boat. Cheers

Comment: Nope. I haven't checked lately though. I'm hoping that 1.5 has brought some more to this area

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to change. A lot of the admin stuff uses regular ASP MVC, so all you really need to do is override a view or a couple of shapes.

For instance, if you wanted to change how the Modules page was rendered, you could do the following:

Create the folder Views/Orchard.Modules/Admin (this matches the module/controller name) in your theme. Inside it create a view called Index.cshtml, and copy and paste the code from the same view in Orchard.Modules - now you can change your version as much as you like and it should override the default view.

For overriding shapes it is a case of just working out the shape name via the shape tracing module and then adding your own version in your Views folder.

All this is fairly generic advice though, again it really does depend on exactly what you want to change.

Comment: Hi - What I want to do is to change the order of the fields/parts for a content type that I've created. I would like to use the existing views to render the editors for the parts/fields,. Any ideas?

Comment: That is certainly something you can do with the placement.info. Would you be able to edit your question to show your placement.info and describe what you are trying to position and where?

Comment: Did you check that the shape names were exactly identical to what's in placement?

Comment: Yes, checked and double checked